# Javascript: embedding a result of a function into a HREF

Tags: javascript, href

I have a javascript function that reformats a link. When a HREF link is clicked, I need to execute this method to finish creating the HREF.

Example JS method:

```
function fixURL (dest, val){
   return dest + val;
}
```

I have an regular HREF and would like to combine the result of the above method to create:

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/" + fixURL('poo','no')>Click me!</a>
```

Is this possible and is it ideal to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `onclick` handler. Note, you're generally better off not using [inline event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) like `onclick="something..."`, so this is just for demonstration purposes.

Also, this will try to open a new window/tab with the search result.

```
<a target="_blank"
   href="https://www.google.com/search?q=chris+rock"
   rel="chris+rock|dave+chappelle"
   onclick="fixURL(this)">Test</a>

function fixURL(el){
    var vals = el.rel.split('|');
    el.href = el.href.replace(vals[0],vals[1]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sxtuz/1/

The same effect, only using DOM event handlers. Note the `id="fixme"` attribute.

```
<a id="fixme"
   target="_blank"
   href="https://www.google.com/search?q=chris+rock"
   rel="chris+rock|dave+chappelle">Test</a>

function fixURL(el){
    var vals = el.rel.split('|');
    el.href = el.href.replace(vals[0],vals[1]);
}
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('fixme').onclick = function(){
        fixURL(this);
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sxtuz/

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the result of a function into a `href`, yes, but the function call cannot be inlined within the HTML. Try this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">A link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    !function(links) {
        links[links.length-1].href+=fixURL('arg1', 'arg2');
    }(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep it as:

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/">Click Me!</a>
```

You can then use jQuery to do:

```
$("a[href='http://www.site.com/']").attr("href", "http://www.site.com/" + fixURL('poo','no'))
```

Explanation:

The `$("a[href='http://www.site.com/']")` matches a  element with an existing `href` equal to `http://www.site.com/`, then changes its href attribute to the second parameter that you pass in. In this case `"http://www.site.com/" + fixURL('poo','no')`

Comment: jQuery to do this? It's fine as a recommendation or as an alternative, but the question isn't tagged [tag:jquery] and it's a really simple task.

Comment: Fair enough. Figured I'd suggest it in case the asker is using jQuery elsewhere and just didn't mention it.

Comment: There are purists that see jQuery as a type of crutch. If you find yourself typing some variation of *if you are using/can use jQuery*, consider whether or not jQuery is really necessary to answer the question. You will at times get downvotes if you're too lassez-faire about "suggesting" it. Just be certain there's enough reason to realistically improve the approach and make the argument as strong as possible, or consider not answering. `:)`